# Decrypting Hexadecimal

Tags: cipher

All I know is that this is in hexadecimal, after that I can't figure out how to decrypt this:

```
30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 30 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 30 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 37 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 37 20 30 36 31 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 30 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 31 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 32 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 31 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 33 20 30 36 31 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 37 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 37 20 30 36 30 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 33 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 37 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 34 20 30 36 36 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 34 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 33 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 35 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 30 20 30 36 32 20 30 34 30 20 30 36 31 20 30 36 36 20 30 36 37
```

Comment: Do you have any more information to give at all that might be relevant?

Answer (score 7):

***Author's note:*** I would NOT recommend clicking any of the links in this post unless you are willing to see some creepy stuff.

---

Continuing on from where Deusovi left off:

The [Youtube channel in question](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDjfFteq5Y7lMx3szf4Z5Bw) has the name "Ahriman Ratum". In Latin, this means "Ahriman Ratified", where [Ahriman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angra_Mainyu) appears to be some sort of destructive spirit in the religion of [Zoroastrianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism).

The user's description is hex encoded twice and reads:

> To the creator of epsat.webs.com and https://www.youtube.com/user/nargargole : This is a representation of your

<sub>(It appears the user did not realize the description has a length limit)</sub>

The user's only video has a description which is hex encoded twice and reversed. Decoded, it reads:

> Yazamaide Ahriman

**Warning: Here is where it gets more creepy.**

The video appears to be taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYxyglXZ3Ev9JpNZ0sJzAHA) channel, called "Vorsk Backup Channel". From what I've read, and pieced together, this is a backup of a channel called "Vorsk" which was terminated by YouTube due to Community Guidelines violations.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr9B0-xkAJk) video of his criticizes the user [Takedownman](https://www.youtube.com/user/Takedownman) for reporting his channel.

Some of the videos of his channel seem to focus around the murder of [JonBenét Ramsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_JonBen%C3%A9t_Ramsey). [One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJbIcrpdtO4), entitled Lou Smit, shows a wobbly camera walking up to his grave. This is creepy, as I feel a hoaxer would not go to such lengths to make his channel 'look' creepy. [Lou Smit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lou_Smit) was an officer that worked on the JonBenét case. He protested that the Ramseys, who were the main suspects, were innocent, and the case remains unresolved. The description reads, after trivial decoding:

> He was right, he was right. They didn't listen to him

I'll add more later to this post. Enough creep for one day.

Comment: No need to continue further. This is all I need to know. I'm gonna go not sleep now.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) hex to string converter yields this:

```
061 065 060 040 061 066 064 040 061 066 064 040 061 066 060 040 061 066 063 040 060 067 062 040 060 065 067 040 060 065 067 040 061 066 067 040 061 066 067 040 061 066 067 040 060 065 066 040 061 067 061 040 061 065 067 040 061 066 065 040 061 066 064 040 061 066 065 040 061 064 062 040 061 064 065 040 060 065 066 040 061 064 063 040 061 065 067 040 061 065 065 040 060 065 067 040 061 064 063 040 061 065 060 040 061 064 061 040 061 065 066 040 061 065 066 040 061 064 065 040 061 065 064 040 060 065 067 040 061 062 065 040 061 060 063 040 061 060 064 040 061 065 062 040 061 064 066 040 061 060 066 040 061 066 064 040 061 064 065 040 061 066 061 040 060 066 065 040 061 063 061 040 060 066 067 040 061 065 064 040 061 061 065 040 061 067 060 040 060 066 063 040 061 066 063 040 061 067 062 040 061 064 066 040 060 066 064 040 061 063 062 040 060 066 065 040 061 060 062 040 061 066 067
```

And using an octal to ASCII converter yields:

```
150 164 164 160 163 072 057 057 167 167 167 056 171 157 165 164 165 142 145 056 143 157 155 057 143 150 141 156 156 145 154 057 125 103 104 152 146 106 164 145 161 065 131 067 154 115 170 063 163 172 146 064 132 065 102 167
```

Octal to ASCII again yields a Youtube channel:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDjfFteq5Y7lMx3szf4Z5Bw

Comment: Looks like octal to me, not decimal

Comment: @Tryth: Thanks, no idea how I missed that.